# Check if Jquery Post request result is full loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use $.post and I put the result in a html div. Sometimes the $.post request stops before the result content is full loaded.
How can I procced the $.post request till all is loaded?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#content").html('<img height="150" width="150" src="spinner.gif" id="spinner"></div>');
    $.post("getdata.php", 
    { id:  "<?php echo $id ?>",
    language:  "<?php echo $language ?>"
    }, function(result){        
        $("#content").html(result);         
    });
});
```

Comment: write your code in `success` or `complete` `callback` function

Comment: Isn't callback function supplied as a third parameter to `$.post()` supposed to run ONLY upon successful request execution?

Answer (score -1):

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
      alert( "success" );
    })
      .done(function() {
        alert( "second success" ); //You can append your html in this function
      })
      .fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
      })
      .always(function() {
        alert( "finished" );
      }

);
```

Follow [this](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) as a reference.

Comment: code + link only answers aren't answers IMO - add an explanation to help the OP understand the issue and solution. Helping them develop their developing skills :p